# Using in MotionEvent and a Dialog after animation has stopped

Tags: java, android

What's the best way to know if the image has totally stopped rotating when handling `MotionEvent` with a `Dialog` view?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.animatedImage);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog (Player3AccessActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);

    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            start =1000;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            start= start +250;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Random random=new Random();
            int toDegrees= random.nextInt(start +1000);

            iv.animate()
              .rotation(toDegrees)
              .setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator())
              .setDuration(1000);
            dialog.show();
            break;
    }
    return(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically create an animation object like this :

```
RotateAnimation r = new RotateAnimation(0f, -90f,200,200);
    r.setStartOffset(1000);
    r.setDuration(1000);
    r.setFillAfter(true);
    r.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //
            //Execute your code.(SHOW DIALOG)
            //

            System.out.println("DONE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

Then start the animation like this :

```
     //
    //START ANIMATION
    //

    yourObjectToRotate.startAnimation(r);
```

The code you provide inside the onAnimationEnd() will be executed when the rotation animation is completed.

Comment: The image not rotate randomly

Comment: You are calculating the random number right...? So in my code just change the -90f with the random number you get like if you get 200, then set it as -200f in the above code

Comment: no more code in the onAnimationRepeat() method sir? the image cant even rotate when i click it when i trt your code,  lets same i put in my onAnimation is. Dialog dialog =new Dialog (this);  dialog.setContentView (R.layout.custom); dialog.show(); ...iwanted to rotate an image view (my object).